# How to control the rendering in the frontend, only rendering 30post at once

Tags: vuejs3, inertiajs, laravel-9

Environment:
backend: Laravel 9,
frontend: VueJs 3, InertiaJs

My expected result is to render or pass over the data to/in the frontend when the user scrolled to the bottom. Then it triggered something to render more data/post.

**Controller**

```
/**
 * Rendering the Explore page.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return \Inertia\Response
 */
public function show(Request $request)
{
    $posts = Post::with('author')
        ->inRandomOrder()
        ->get;

    return Inertia::render('Explore/Explore', [
        'canLogin' => Route::has('login'),
        'canRegister' => Route::has('register'),
        'posts' => $posts,
    ]);
}
```

For now, it just rendered all the data from the database. I have a show more button in the frontend, and it only shows up when posts more than 20.

```
<div v-show="posts.length > 30"
     class="pointer-events-none absolute inset-x-0 
            bottom-0 flex justify-center pt-32 pb-8">
    <button type="button"
            class="click pointer-events-auto relative flex h-12 items-center 
            rounded-lg bg-white px-6 text-sm font-semibold 
            text-black hover:bg-gray-200">
        Show more...
    </button>
</div>
```

I aspect to solve this in the backend, so when "show more is clicked," it posts to a route and pass more data to the page, but not sure how to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `axios.get` in the frontend to send the request and receive data as json.

And in the backend you will need add

```
if ($request->wantsJson()) {
            return response()->json($posts)
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
                ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
        }
```

be sure to remember to return the header for the `CORS`